# XCode 7: Can't Push git

Tags: git, xcode7

After I updated XCode 7 i can't push my code to git repo. However i can pull the repo. I am getting 
`Unexpected HTTP status code: 411 (-1)` error.
I have checked 411 error code shows up when the length of the code is high. But this is not my problem. I have done:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But this did not solved my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to push via console or only via Xcode? What do you have in `git status` and `git log`?

Comment: I am trying to push via Xcode. I can push code via Console. I can get usual things by using `git status` and `git log`

Comment: Ok, but what is the output of `git status` and `git log` (only 2 newest commits is enough)? I want to validate what exactly did Xcode stage and why is it wrong.

Comment: same issue. Use terminal to push is Okay , but Xcode 7 not work.

Comment: Same problem here!! Unexpected HTTP status code: 411 (-1) ...everything works from the console. Xcode however, fails to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `SSH` instead of using `HTTP`. This [Changing http link to ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) key helped me to figure out.